# How to remove node when become outside the scene in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

I am trying to delete node when goes out side the scene and i tried this method to do it

```
if( CGRectIntersectsRect(node.frame, view.frame) ) {
   // Don't delete your node
} else {
   // Delete your node as it is not in your view
}
```

but it seems not working any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have written a comment to delete a node... of course it does not work :-)

Comment: hhhh the code is "node.removeFromParent()" its too obvious so i didnt type it

Comment: Ok :) So next question, where did you put that code?

Comment: i think maybe this the problem , i put it in didmovetoview method i dont where i should put it

Comment: Yes that's the problem. Please take a look at my answer and let me know if it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to be the best approach by a performance point of view but if you override the `update` method in your scene you will be able to write code that gets executed each frame so.

```
class GameScene : SKScene {

    var arrow : SKSpriteNode?

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        super.update(currentTime)

        if let
            arrow = arrow,
            view = self.view
        where
            CGRectContainsRect(view.frame, arrow.frame) == false &&
            CGRectIntersectsRect(arrow.frame, view.frame) == false {
                arrow.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

### Considerations

Please keep in mind that every code you write inside the update method is executed **each frame** (60 times per second on a 60fps game) so you should be very careful about that.
Typical things you don't want to write inside the `update` unless it is strictly necessary:

1. **creation** of objects
2. big **loops**
3. **recursive** calls
4. any crazy code that requires too much **time** to be executed

Hope this helps.

Comment: i put it as you said but it gives me compiling error " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Did you put it inside your scene?

Comment: Ok, how is `node` declared? Something like `var node: SKNode!` ?

Comment: var arrow : SKSpriteNode!

Comment: thanks and sorry if i bothering the work it seems work but it remove it inside the scene before it go outside the scene

Comment: Yes, it is happening because `CGRectIntersectsRect` does check an intersection between the rectangle of the scene and the rectangle that contains your sprite. I am going to update my answer but you'll need to test it.

Comment: Good luck with your game ;-)